# How to pass more than one value in QueryString and how to retrieve it in other form

Tags: asp.net

How I can pass more than two value and how I can retrieve it again in different page and also in same page. If I retrieve in same page and perform operation like delete, how can I do that?

Comment: Please do some research into the issue and show what you've attempted as a result of that research.

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["Delete"].ToString() == "delete")
                    DeleteData();
                else
                    GetData();
            }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried. You may want to read [ask] for tips on what is expected of questions.

Comment: Do you already know how to pass one value via QueryString?  Could you show us that code, so we can show how to change it for two values.

Comment: I pass one value like <a href='UserUpdate.aspx?id=" + id + "'>Edit</a>

Comment: Response.Redirect("xxx.aspx?id=val1&flag=val2");

In xx,aspx.cs
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
string flag = Request.QueryString["flag"];